# Is there a way to use Windows with GUI capability on Dockers

Tags: docker, window, continuous-integration, windows-server-container

I'm thinking is there a way to leverage on Dockers concept for my windows base Desktop application. I need to run GUI test, performance test, workflow test etc.. for each build. What I currently do is use Hyper-V with pre setup different OS images.

Is there a easy way to achieve same thing using docker concept. As I know this can be achieve for non GUI application. but how about the GUI base desktop apps.